# Converting 'foreach' to 'for' loop or vice versa with ReSharper possible?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, for-loop, foreach

Is it possible to mark a foreach loop code block and convert it to a for loop with ReSharper?

Or with Visual Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep ReShaper can do that. Tested it in VS2010 + R#5

Before:

```
        var a = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
        foreach (var i in a)
        {

        }
```

After:

```
    var a = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
    for (int index = 0; index < a.Length; index++)
    {
        var i = a[index];
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you're iterating over List so that you can access the elements by an index, then hit `Alt-Enter` on the foreach keyword.

Comment: Wow got a downvote after 6 years! Care to share why?

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say it's because the answer (although fully answers the question) does no explanation of how to do this. Which is done in another answer and in a comment on yours. The OP does not ask how, but it should be safe to assume if he has to ask if it's possible, he wouldn't know how to do it and would most likely want to know that as well.

Comment: Lol! Another one

Answer (score 3):

You can even do this without Resharper now (Tested with Visual Studio 2017 on a C# project):

```
int[] array = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };

foreach (int item in array)
{
   int someVariable = item;
   //Your logic
}
```

Becomes

```
int[] array = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
   int item = array[i];
   int someVariable = item;
  //Your logic
}
```

(And vice versa!)
To make this change, you just have to click on the "foreach" or "for" word, and look for a screwdriver icon shown on the left, click on it and select "convert to 'for'" / "convert to 'foreach'". 
(see the link below if you never saw this icon)

Hope it helped someone (even if this is a *very old* post!)

[Visual Studio screwdriver icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWILv.png)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer since it actually tells you how to do it.

Comment: That is called Quick Fixes (In VS terms), you can invoke it with `⌥↵` here on VS for Mac (Same as Rider for invoking _context actions_ or _intentions_)

Answer (score 2):

works fine, just as rdkleine said and the sample is working great.
BUT: it if your collection is a simple `IEnumerable<T>` it won't work (reasonably).